# drop down bar goes back up on second click (in inputbox) because it's inside animated div - jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, html, input, toggle

at the moment i have this

```
            <div id="beau">

                <div>
                <input type="text" id="lun" name="lun" size="24" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'User Name':this.value;" value="User Name"             
                style="position:absolute; background-color:transparent; border-style:none; margin-top:53px; margin-left:35px;" />
                </div>

                <img src="_images/Rollovers/drop bar export.png" alt="extras" width="877" height="160" border="0" />

            </div> 


        <script type='text/javascript'>

    $("#beau").toggle(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({marginTop: 738}, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({marginTop: 680}, "fast");
    });

        </script>
```

and what the problem is, is that i will click the "beau" div to drop down the "input box" and the image (both inside the "beau" div) and that all works fine but but when i click in the "input box" to type text the drop bar goes back up again. i know why it does it and I've tried a few things to get it working but i just can't get it. thanks for all your help guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a handler for the input that stops propagation to the div:

```
    $('#lun').click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation(); 
    });
```